# Find cell by value with google api v4 (google sheets)

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-sheets, google-api, google-sheets-api

can I find cell by value using google api v4 ?, in my task I want change background color `if cell_value == my_value`.

I know only one variant it`s:

1. using gspread I can find cell coordinates
2. using google api v4 I can change background color

but I want to use only google api v4, because find cell by value using gspread very slowly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting value of cell using Sheets API is supported. Check the [Sheets API Reading guide](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values#reading).
Code samples for reading are found in [Basic Reading](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/reading).

**Read a single range**

The following spreadsheets.values.get request reads the values stored in the range Sheet1!A1:D5 and returns them in the response. Empty trailing rows and columns are omitted.

The request protocol is shown below. The Reading and Writing Values guide shows how to implement reads in different languages using the Google API client libraries.

```
GET https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/spreadsheetId/values/Sheet1!A1:D5
```

Comment: if i want to use spreadsheets.batchUpdate, i need get row and column where my_text present. of course i can read all data in sheet and return row and column where my text present  but i think google api has another method to get cell coordinates by text

Comment: @OsiaButorin You think? Where's your reference?

Comment: I do not have a reference to this question)) but if row and column need for batchUpdate method, then there must be a method of searching for these values and return their. Or not ?

Comment: There's now getRow or getColumn for SheetsAPI but you can check the [Row and Column Operations](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/rowcolumn) .

Comment: absolutely, but Row and Column Operations don`r resolve my problem to find cell coordinates on sheet

Comment: I think what he is asking for is to find a "cell" by "value" like a search

Answer (score -1):

this is how the JSON should look like:

```
{
  "find": string,
  "replacement": string,
  "matchCase": boolean,
  "matchEntireCell": boolean,
  "searchByRegex": boolean,
  "includeFormulas": boolean,

  // Union field scope can be only one of the following:
  "range": {
    object(GridRange)
  },
  "sheetId": number,
  "allSheets": boolean,
  // End of list of possible types for union field scope.
}
```

select just one of the scope options (range, sheetID or allSheets).

Comment: which sheet api does I use for this request body ? sorry I can't find it.